# How to find an Azure SQL Database connection name

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-logic-apps

I have created an Azure SQL database and now want to use that database in an Azure Logic App where I need to connect to the database using connection name of that SQL database. I'm following this [tutorial from Azure official team](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-sqlazure) where at one step I need to enter connection name. But I cannot find the connection name in Azure Portal for my Azure SQL Database. If you look at the `Connection Name` field in the dialog box of `step 3`, you see you need to enter the connection name. **Question**: How can I find connection name of my Azure SQL db?

**UPDATE**

I'm using this [tutorial from Azure official documents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-get-started-portal) to create Azure SQL db and I don't see any place where connection name was provided by me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enter any name.Some info from Documentation .

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The connection name is a name you provide for the collection of properties related to your connection to Azure SQL DB.

Comment: What is the `collection of properties`? I have just added an `UPDATE` section to my post above.